# Create ordered list plus generate input field HTML & JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have here the complete code of what I have applied and tried. Using the JS below, I got the display of the ordered list wrongly. It must be in `1,2,3 ...` (so on and forth). For this, it sticked to `1.,1.,1. ...`. Another is that, using the JS below, how to customize it that I will get `dynamic` input fields? Because what if I'll input 5? The result of the fields must be 5 in number also. But what happened, 5 fields are added/appended to the current number of fields (sample, I inputted 3 before and 3 fields displayed so when 5 is inputted, there are 8 fileds in all). What I want is the exact number of fields from the number being inputted. (not that good at JS but I am badly wanting to learn its nature).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("ul").each(function() {
    $(this).find("li").each(function(count) {
       $(this)
         .css("list-style-type", "none")
         .prepend("<div class='listnumber'>" + (count + 1) + ".</div>");
       });
    });
 })    
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name="cand_no"]').on('change', function() {
         if (this.value != '') {
             var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);

             for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
                 var $cloned = $('.template tbody').clone();
                 $('#studentTable tbody').append($cloned.html());
         }
     });
  })
</script>   

</head>
 <body>
      <p>
         <label><strong>No.: </strong></label>
         <label><input name="cand_no" type="number" placeholder="Enter no. of fields." /></label>
         <div class="clear"></div>
     </p>
     <div class="cand_fields">
       <table id="studentTable" width="630" border="0">
            <tr>
               <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><input name="cand_name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="required" /></td>
            </tr>
       </table>

    </div>

    <div class="template" style="display: none">
       <table>
        <tr >
           <td><ul><li><input name="cand_name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="required" /></li></ul></td>



           </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks a million..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".template ul li").css("list-style-type", "none").prepend("<div class='listnumber'></div>");
})
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $tmpl = $('.template tbody'),
        $target = $('#studentTable tbody');
    $('[name="cand_no"]').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value != '') {
            var val = (parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0) + 2;
            var len = $target.children().length;

            if (val < len) {
                $target.children().slice(val).remove();
            } else {
                for (var i = len; i < val; i++) {
                    $($tmpl.html()).appendTo($target).find('.listnumber').text(i - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rbkDA/)